# Xamarin UI test: Read out visible elements that are not shown with Repl tree command (Grid)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I've got a xaml page, split by a Grid element:

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource Key=MainGrid}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Key=White}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="12*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="69*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Later I fill the second raw with two labels:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Spacing="10" Margin="{DynamicResource Key=ContentMargin}">
    <Label Text="Text1" AutomationId="Text1"/>
    <Label Text="Text2" AutomationId="Text2"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Within the page of the app both labels are displayed, but my problem is, that the test automatin can't read the second text.
If I use Repl and enter the "tree" command, the second element is not read out at all:

```
[Platform_DefaultRenderer]
    [LabelRenderer] label: "Text1_Container"
        [FormsTextView] id: "NoResourceEntry-18",  label: "Text1",  text: "Text1"
[Platform_DefaultRenderer]
```

If I add 2% to the Height of Row 2 (and subtract 2% of Row 3), both elements are visible for the UI test.
Why is that the case? Can I change anything except of changing the Row Height to read out the content of "Text2"?
I use android 8.1 for the app.

Answer (score 2):

And what queries have you tried to access the second element? If you just need to get the text of the second element try using:

```
app.Query(c => c.All().Class("FormsTextView").Index(1)).First().Text
```

It should find the element even if it's not visible for the "tree" command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped a lot. I used following: "app.Query(c => c.All().Class("FormsTextView")).ToList()". Afterwards I performed on the returned list a Where(...) to find the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, Xamarin.UITest has only access to views which are currently on screen and slightly beyond. Therefore, try to scroll down using `app.ScrollDown(...)`.

You will not face that problem on iOS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but that does not help. I've got fixed (height) raws. It is not scrollable. And as I said, I can see the whole content with my eyes, but not with the tree command.